# Queue Members are not getting the emails when condition meet?

Tags: apex, email, queue

I have created a queue in salesforce based on my code only one queue member get the email notification.

```
public class CaseUserHelper {

    public static void updateCaseStage(List<Case> cases) {

             List<ID> cIds = new List<ID>();

             List<Case_User__c> cuser = New  List<Case_User__c>();
             Map<ID, Case_User__c> cusermap = new Map<ID, Case_User__c>();

             Set<String> skillSet = new Set<String>();
             List<String> skillSetList = new List<String>();

             for(Case c: cases){

                   if(c.Status == 'New') {
                   cIds.add(c.Id); //add case ids.
                   }     
                   skillSet.add(c.CaseRelatedTo__c);
             }   
           skillSetList.addAll(skillSet);    

         //available users               
           try{
                   List<Case_User__c> availableCaseUsers = [SELECT AvailableUsers__c, Timings__c, SkillSet__c  FROM Case_User__c where Availability__c = TRUE ORDER BY Last_Case_Allocated_Time__c ASC];
                 //List<Case_User__c> availableCaseUsers = Database.query(queryString);
                    integer i=0;
                    integer nomatchingSkillset = availableCaseUsers.size();
                    for(Case c: cases){
                        for(; i<=availableCaseUsers.size();i++){
                        if(availableCaseUsers.get(i).SkillSet__c.contains(c.CaseRelatedTo__c)){
                          c.OwnerId = availableCaseUsers.get(i).AvailableUsers__c;
                          availableCaseUsers.get(i).Last_Case_Allocated_Time__c = DateTime.now();
                          cusermap.put(availableCaseUsers.get(i).id, availableCaseUsers.get(i));
                         } else {
                              nomatchingSkillset--;
                              if(nomatchingSkillset == 0){
                                  //TODO assign to case queue

                                     User u =[SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.DeveloperName ='CaseQueue')];
                                     String us = u.Email;

                                      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                                      String[] toAddresses = new String[] {us};
                                      mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses );
                                      mail.setSubject('No Users available to handle this case');
                                      mail.plainTextBody='handle this case';
                                      Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});

                                  break;
                              }
                              continue;
                        }
                        if(i>=availableCaseUsers.size()){
                            i=0;
                        }
                        break;
                     }      
                }
                 if(!cusermap.isEmpty()) {
                    update cusermap.values();
                 }
            }catch(System.DmlException e){
                 System.debug('Missing the required field in record');
            }catch(Exception e){
                 System.debug('An Error Occured at:' +e.getMessage());
            }finally{
                 System.debug('This is block just for closing the class');
            }      
   }
}
```

Comment: anyone suggest me to get the queue emails?

Answer (score 0):

At the line where you make that query on `User` based on an inner query on  `GroupMember` you are assigning the result to a single instance of `User`. Have you tried assigning it to a list of users (`List<User>`) instead, since you want more than one user receiving the email? This seems to be an issue.

```
// enter "nomatchingSkillset == 0" condition...
List<User> users = [select id, email from user where id in (select userorgroupid from groupmember where group.developername = 'CaseQueue')];
List<String> addresses = new List<String>();
for (User u : users) {
    addresses.add(u.Email);
}
// ... build your Messaging.SingleEmailMessage as usual...
```